# How do I produce a single file that can be run by clicking on it in, and for, Linux?

Tags: linux

How do I as a dev make it simple to package and deliver software to a Linux user?

**Relates to**

1. Computers (Desktop)
2. Illegal forced Monopoly Stores and plucky alternative stores
3. Compile from abandoned source, you're on your own user, this is not a product.

**Relates to released products.**

Does **not** relate to

a) commandline

b) makefiles

c) build scripts

d) sources

e) online or offline projects

*I want to find out if major Linux OS distros are capable of things that were possible before on all OSes.*

**Examples:**

I. Download an executable file, click to run.

II. Download archive, unarchive it to a folder, click one file in it to run the software

III. No more examples. This is what the question pertains to.

**Target platform specified by:**

1.1 OS platform target

1.2 GUI (if not included in OS platform target)

1.3 Frameworks provided by 1.1 or 1.2.

**In short:** Imagine a serious developer. How do I deliver a software product on Linux? Download link, click, run.

(I come from a corporate environment, so I don't yet have the reputation on this forum to create the tag, "deliverable".)

Note that the **form** of the deliverable is not questioned here. Examples could be very simple:

A. Draw a rect on the default monitor

B. Open a window and do nothing else.

C. Open a file to a standard file output, write characters to it, and close it.

Comment: What assumptions can this single executable make about its environment? For example, if it's a graphical application can it assume there is a GUI? If so, is it SDL or Wayland or X11 or something different to all of those? If it needs a graphical environment and there isn't one, should this have been packaged as part of the executable too?

Comment: I'm going to guess you'll say "of course not", so then you have the concept of dependencies. And then you need a package manager to manage those dependencies. And behold you've reinvented `rpm` and `dpkg`, and then `yum`/`dnf` and `apt`. You can provide a single package but someone needs to think about the packages that provide the necessary software to support the application

Comment: What @roaima wrote + some Silly question : In nowadays context of ever increased security risks, who (as a potential user) would want that ? As far as I am concerned and not being paranoid, I have never run any software that had not previously been built on my system.

Comment: I have added details such that the form of the executable will be invariable, to free it from dependencies. CPUs can run programs. In fact, that's all they do. The question is rather, why is it so impossible specifically on some OSes? The key is the target platform. When delivered for a target platform, any program can certainly run and deliver the expected results. Not all programs require dependencies other than that from any OS, as you can see from the simple examples.

Comment: Do you mean your software would not depend on whatever sort of libc ? or that some sort of libc would be statically linked to the software ?

Comment: Appimage software can run by a single click tho sometimes it could be necessary to set `execute permissions`. Another example, if you have `jar` files (and these don't need dependencies) they can be run with a single click but as I said before you might need to set `execute permissions`. You can configure your system to open an specific file (jar,txt,mp4, etc.) with a specific application.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon : jar files don't need dependencies ? Errrr ? A JRE at least I presume.

Comment: @MC68020 my question is as stated. How do I produce a file that can be executed? OSes are capable of it. CPUs are capable of it. A. B. and C. were possible in the 1980s and earlier. If I can link a file that does either with a download and a click after installation of the OS, the question is answered. If we can no longer do this, every piece of software can be deprecated by any of its dependencies. Given target platform, how do I produce a binary? Still no problem on several OSes. Linux however is different.

Comment: @MC68020  yeah you're right. I had to be more specific with that. What I meant with `and these don't need dependencies` I was not affirming that `jar` files don't require anything of dependencies.  I wrote `and these don't need dependencies` as a `condition` (assuming that jre and other dependencies are installed).
I had to detail better that but I'm not native English speaker and maybe I didn't use the correct words.

Comment: Welcome, could you give an example of other OS doing what you want?

Comment: You are absolutely correct in ONE thing : When writing  *"Ievery piece of software can be deprecated by any of its dependencies."* Because this is absolutely true! You are refering to the days (I've known) when there was no such as thing as dynamically linked libraries. Whatever library needed had to be statically linked and the resulting executable could be run standalone.

Comment: Welcome @schrodingerscatcuriosity, I'm looking for a correspondence to a binary executable in Linux. We all know the context and the work that went into making common packages easier to "install", but installation is not necessary for an OS or a CPU. The function of an OS is to run executable files, all else is a dictate from the authors what else it should do. In commercial cases that translates to Control Freak Monopolies, in the opposite case it translate to compile a project from source yourself, we're going to assume to know what it takes, good luck dev! But an OS is for users only.

Comment: Sorry but I just give up. I had initially thought you had an honest misunderstanding about a couple of technical points, your last comment appears to me versing your question into *political* considerations.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson, so, what would be a non-Linux example of the thing you're looking for? I mean, a technical example. You said you're "looking for a correspondence to a binary executable in Linux", and I'm not exactly sure of what you mean: Linux has binary executables the same as any other general purpose OS.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson The Linux community is quite decentralized, evident from the number of distributions and package repositories. Hence, I am having a hard time determining just who the "Control Freak Monopolies" are in regards to Linux software.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson I posted an earnest answer below but, as prior comments point out, you seem to have a non-technical agenda which, while not hidden, is also not clear. I'm sure taking a guess is a bad idea... nonetheless: you seem upset over the increasing control commercial OS vendors are taking over end users systems (including locking out developers), yet want a similar non-technical "Consumer Platform" to develop and, I assume, sell for. You allude to the answer: find a [distro](https://distrowatch.com/) that has your goals, or roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing the questions, based on clarifications in comments.

*What is a binary executable in Linux?*

It's an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file with the [execute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) bit set. Binary code and references to shared libraries are stored in the file so final linking is done when the executable is launched by the OS (similarly to Frameworks on Mac OS or DLLs on windows). If you are concerned about this last step introducing dependencies, look into the [suckless project](https://suckless.org/) which promotes static linking for just those reasons.

*How do I create a binary executable?*

In the 'Nix tradition, you write a program in C, and use the `cc` ("Compile C", or "C Compiler", either one works) command. This will compile and link your C code to produce an ELF file with binary code for the architecture you're running on. There are many different tools to manage this process when multiple source files are used, from command-line `make` to GUI IDEs. Compilers and interpreters are available for a wide range of programming languages, so you aren't limited to C.

*Imagine a serious developer. How do I deliver a software product on Linux? Download link, click, run.*

Because Linux is run on a range of processor architectures and there isn't a ["FAT" binary standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary#FatELF:_Universal_binaries_for_Linux), this isn't possible. After downloading the appropriate executable for their CPU, the user may have to set the execute bit manually (easily done from the command line but more challenging from a GUI). Ultimately what's on a user's system depends on the distro, the installation options used during the install, and what packages the user has installed since - most distros use a [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) to install additional software while resolving dependencies. While the Mac OS and Windows each have a single [Desktop Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment), GNU/Linux has many (or may be installed without one); beyond aesthetic variations, each may adhere to different interface standards (such as emulating Windows' shortcut keys), and each may depend to different degrees on the command line.

That said, you might be interested in projects like Canonical's [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/store), which, along with Ubuntu itself, seems to try to appeal to users who might fall into the category of "consumers of products" as well as more technical folks.

A few things in your question could be clarified:

By restricting your focus to "Desktop" computers, I'm assuming you don't mean to exclude laptops, but instead are interested in "Personal Computers" or "Workstations," and not servers or embedded systems, where Linux is commonplace.

I don't know what you mean by "Illegal forced Monopoly" nor "plucky alternative" stores, but if your concern is of a legal nature, you might try Stack Exchange's [law site](https://law.stackexchange.com).

I'm interpreting the bulk of your question is to focus attention on delivering software in binary form, not introduce a different concern.

The statement *I want to find out if major Linux OS distros are capable of things that were possible before on all OSes* is unclear; different OSes have had very different functionality over the years.

Coming from a "corporate environment" should not bear on your reputation score on this site; while [tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_tracking) could be used to identify users and take actions that might influence scores, I have seen no evidence of this nor am I even aware of any claims it is happening.

Each function you include in the list at the end of your question can be provided by software in binary form, with the caveat that the user may not be running a compatible environment - e.g. your software may not be able to open a window on a console only install.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring whatever *political* consideration / rant that part of your question as well a some of your comments vociferate.

---

> How do I as a dev make it simple to package and deliver software to a
> Linux user?

You get in touch with distro devs and convince them to include your software into their repository.
Why ? Because the vast majority of Linux users won't install whatever software outside of the package manager supported by their distribution.

PERIOD!

Additional note following comments :

Linux can of course happily run whatever executable code leaving no external reference unresolved.
In other words, if your C code uses *printf* or *whatever* function, you must provide the code for printf or that whatever function as part of your code or statically link the library providing the code for those functions.

Nothing changed compared to the 1980 ages you refer to.

You can rather easily design (I won't say anything about distributing since I'm just ignorant of all those possible licenses) whatever **standalone** semigraphical application statically linking some libc libm and libcurses.

Big problems will of course occur as soon as your application just cannot… standalone. That is when you'll want your application to be client of whatever server.

You mention opening a window… ? (with hopefully respect to all other windows users would have opened) you'll need the help of not whatever X server but THE X server currently running on the user's system.

Of course you could statically link the associated client libs. But can you predict for sure which server in which version users will be running ?

If not then… you'll have to statically link all the client libs of all possible X / database /… server in all possible supported versions…

Whatever normal user will necessarily rant for the ram wasted since… the appropriate client lib is already loaded in ram as shared lib.

So no ! Things have not changed from early beginnings. Apart from… may be… your expectations. :-P

Comment: I didn't think of lobbying distro devs - that is a good idea. You could also just "align" with a distro, testing and keeping your SW up to date with whatever changes come along. You could try the suckless project for a toolchain based on static linking. On the other hand, WebOS or Android are good Linuxes(?) to avoid the command line. Chrome OS is another Linux option that is designed for novice and non-technical users.

Comment: One more thing: if you don't want to depend on an X server or Wayland compositor, you can write for DRM.

Comment: @DanielMGessel : Lobbying distro devs was the right path, for me… at the end of the day. ;-). Not, to be honest, without having needed to rework (swearing a lot) quite a lot of things because of their quality requirements. But I must acknowledge… at the end of the day that my code is actually much more robust than it was initially thanks to their **#@@!!#!** demands. :-) Keeping in line with a distro is also a possibility which also would require hard work. Well… at the end of the day… you'll have to work hard! You just choose your path… expecting it will be the lightest ;-)

Comment: "_You get in touch with distro devs and convince them to include your software into their repository._" that will allow you to produce a single file executable for a single distribution. Let's say Ubuntu. You now need different packaging - and probably compilation - for every other distribution, whether Debian, Mint, Fedora, Arch, Manjaro... and many many others too numerous to mention

Comment: Don't most distros compile their own packages from source (Debian), or depend on a "parent distro" (Ubuntu is a child of debian) or expect the user to compile them (Gentoo)?